# Make a texture use coordinates

Tags: c++, image, textures, sfml, move

I am trying to make a texture follow a different texture. I already got its coordinates but I don´t know how to make the other use those.

I tried:

```
playerObj2.image.move(sf::Vector2(xPosition,yPosition));
```

being `xPosition` and `yPosition` playerObj2's coordinates. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The move() function pushes an object in a given direction, it doesn't move the object to that position. For example, if playerObj2.image was at x=100, y=100 and you called playerObj2.image.move(sf::Vector2(50, 50)), the image would move to x=150, y=150. You should replace the code above with:

```
playerObj2.image.setPosition(sf::Vector2(xPosition,yPosition));
```